# Ошибка 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, list

Дан файл с рандомными буквами различного регистра. Пытаюсь считать их и записать в список сделав нижний регистр. Но при вызове вывода пишет: 'list' object is not callable. В чем загвоздка?

```
f=open('dataset.txt','r')
words=f.read().splitlines()
my_list=(words)
print(my_list(key=str.lower))
```

Comment: `my_list(key=str.lower)`  В результате выполнения вот этого кода, Вы что ожидаете получить? 
Ну и заодно вот этого `my_list=(words)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
f=open('dataset.txt','r')
words=f.read().lower()
f.close()
print(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Разберём по порядку...
`words` у вас список.
`my_list` у вас равен `words`, т.е. тоже список.
А дальше вы пишите `my_list(...)`, т.е. "вызываете" `my_list` как будто это функция. На что вам сообщение об ошибке как бы и намекает.

Comment: Точно, невнимателен. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('dataset.txt','r')
words=f.read().splitlines()
my_list=(words)
print(my_list(key=str.lower()))
```